# Save excel as pdf, name of the file as a variables value

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to save a selection to pdf, everything works fine except that I cant save the file with and specific name, I want the name to be report Sub  and the date and time ... it works fine except when I try to put today date and time...
this is my code

```
Sub guardar_pdf()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:Q4").Select


    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup

        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = 60
        .PrintGridlines = True
    End With

     Dim fe As String
    fe = now

     With Selection

    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "C:\Users\Diego\Dropbox\informes\informe"&fe, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End With



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple ways you could fix this.

```
fe = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
```

Or ignore that and just do this

```
"C:\Users\Diego\Dropbox\informes\informe" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
```